# Transform multi-columns data in wide to long format

Tags: r, reshape

I have this data

```
dw <- structure(list(ccssid = c(1000023L, 1000043L), base.age = c("22", 
"27"), fu1.age = c("30", "35"), fu2.age = c("33", "37"), fu3.age = c("35", 
"40"), fu7.age = c("38", "42"), fu5.age = c("44", "49"), fu6.age = c("48", 
"52"), base.bmi = c("25.1421", "21.6333"), fu2.bmi = c("25.7959", 
"23.5078"), fu7.bmi = c("25.105", "24.961"), fu5.bmi = c("24.366", 
"24.961"), fu2.MET = c("150", "0"), fu2.CDC = c("Yes", "No"), 
    fu5.MET = c("360", "120"), fu5.CDC = c("Yes", "No"), fu6.MET = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), fu6.CDC = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    base.smk = c(NA, "1"), fu2.smk = c("2", "1"), fu7.smk = c("2", 
    "1"), fu5.smk = c("2", "1"), base.riskydrk = c(NA, "No"), 
    fu7.riskydrk = c("Yes", "Yes"), fu5.riskydrk = c("No", "No"
    ), base.MET = c(NA, NA), base.CDC = c(NA, NA), fu1.bmi = c(NA, 
    NA), fu1.MET = c(NA, NA), fu1.CDC = c(NA, NA), fu1.smk = c(NA, 
    NA), fu1.riskydrk = c(NA, NA), fu2.riskydrk = c(NA, NA), 
    fu3.bmi = c(NA, NA), fu3.MET = c(NA, NA), fu3.CDC = c(NA, 
    NA), fu3.smk = c(NA, NA), fu3.riskydrk = c(NA, NA), fu7.MET = c(NA, 
    NA), fu7.CDC = c(NA, NA), fu6.bmi = c(NA, NA), fu6.smk = c(NA, 
    NA), fu6.riskydrk = c(NA, NA)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I tried this code below to transform this data, but I am not sure why the values of `riskydrk` column are switched with `smk` column in the output. The `smk` column should have values 1,2, but somehow, it is switched with the values of `riskydrk` column. Can someone please help me figure out the issue? Thanks!

```
reshape(dw, direction='long', 
        varying=c('base.age', 'base.bmi', "base.MET", 'base.CDC', "base.smk", "base.riskydrk",
                  'fu1.age', 'fu1.bmi', "fu1.MET", 'fu1.CDC', "fu1.smk", "fu1.riskydrk",
                  'fu2.age', 'fu2.bmi', "fu2.MET", 'fu2.CDC', "fu2.smk", "fu2.riskydrk",
                  'fu3.age', 'fu3.bmi', "fu3.MET", 'fu3.CDC', "fu3.smk", "fu3.riskydrk",
                  'fu7.age', 'fu7.bmi', "fu7.MET", 'fu7.CDC', "fu7.smk", "fu7.riskydrk",
                  'fu5.age', 'fu5.bmi', "fu5.MET", 'fu5.CDC', "fu5.smk", "fu5.riskydrk",
                  'fu6.age', 'fu6.bmi', "fu6.MET", 'fu6.CDC', "fu6.smk", "fu6.riskydrk"),
        timevar='var',
        times=c('base', 'fu1', 'fu2', 'fu3', 'fu7', 'fu5', 'fu6'),
        v.names=c('age', 'bmi', 'MET', 'CDC', 'smk', 'riskydrk'),
        idvar='ccssid')
```

The desired output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired outcome? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is, that your times should be suffixes, so `reshape` is able to guess, which would be way easier.

```
## make prefixes to suffixes
names(dw) <- strsplit(names(dw), '\\.') |> lapply(rev) |> sapply(paste, collapse='.')

reshape(dw, direction='l', idvar='ccssid', varying=sort(names(dw)[-1]))
#               ccssid time age     bmi  CDC  MET riskydrk  smk
# 1000023.base 1000023 base  22 25.1421 <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
# 1000043.base 1000043 base  27 21.6333 <NA> <NA>       No    1
# 1000023.fu1  1000023  fu1  30    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
# 1000043.fu1  1000043  fu1  35    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
# 1000023.fu2  1000023  fu2  33 25.7959  Yes  150     <NA>    2
# 1000043.fu2  1000043  fu2  37 23.5078   No    0     <NA>    1
# 1000023.fu3  1000023  fu3  35    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
# 1000043.fu3  1000043  fu3  40    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
# 1000023.fu5  1000023  fu5  44  24.366  Yes  360       No    2
# 1000043.fu5  1000043  fu5  49  24.961   No  120       No    1
# 1000023.fu6  1000023  fu6  48    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
# 1000043.fu6  1000043  fu6  52    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
# 1000023.fu7  1000023  fu7  38  25.105 <NA> <NA>      Yes    2
# 1000043.fu7  1000043  fu7  42  24.961 <NA> <NA>      Yes    1
```

Comment: Just looking at the results for `fu1`  in `smk` column, I don't think it is correct.

Comment: @MAPK You're right, for some reason `reshape` gets confused if the columns are not `sort`ed by `names`. Please review update.

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is not tagged `dplyr` or `tidyr`, here is a way with package `tidyr`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyr)
})

dw |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -ccssid,
    names_to = c("var", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*)"
  )
#> # A tibble: 14 × 8
#>     ccssid var   age   bmi     MET   CDC   smk   riskydrk
#>      <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#>  1 1000023 base  22    25.1421 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    
#>  2 1000023 fu1   30    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    
#>  3 1000023 fu2   33    25.7959 150   Yes   2     <NA>    
#>  4 1000023 fu3   35    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    
#>  5 1000023 fu7   38    25.105  <NA>  <NA>  2     Yes     
#>  6 1000023 fu5   44    24.366  360   Yes   2     No      
#>  7 1000023 fu6   48    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    
#>  8 1000043 base  27    21.6333 <NA>  <NA>  1     No      
#>  9 1000043 fu1   35    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    
#> 10 1000043 fu2   37    23.5078 0     No    1     <NA>    
#> 11 1000043 fu3   40    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    
#> 12 1000043 fu7   42    24.961  <NA>  <NA>  1     Yes     
#> 13 1000043 fu5   49    24.961  120   No    1     No      
#> 14 1000043 fu6   52    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>